# How do I get a list of the sha's of all commits made in the current branch?

Tags: git

Is there a simple way to get a list of all the SHA's of all the commits made in the current branch back to the point where it was branched from master (I want all the commits and I don't want the output to require the user to hit a key to see those answers that don't fit on the screen)?

Comment: Thanks; I did search for this but for some reason didn't come across that link in my searches.

Comment: For the record, `git --no-pager log mybranch --pretty=format:"%H" --not master` got me what I actually wanted.

Comment: Down-voting git inexperience seems a little harsh but I'll leave this question up as a duplicate in case anyone else is as weak as I am on Git terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `git log mybranchn --pretty=format:"%H" --not master` to get the list of hashes of commits on your branch only without master's commits..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git log --format=format:%H master..` to get a list of just the SHAs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git log` with a proper format:

```
git log --format=format:%H master..your-branch
```

In most of the cases you can use `HEAD` instead of specifying current branch name. Take a look on this page: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head to find out when `HEAD` does not point to the current branch.

Comment: That seems close. Is there any way to list all of them without having to press a key to advance after the first screen full?

Comment: @JonCage You could pipe it through `tee` and git won't turn on the pager.

Comment: @alex: I found that adding `--no-pager` before the `log` parameter sorted it but thanks.